# how does projection happen in arcgis with regards to spatial reference

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I have a map loaded in my Mapview called mMapview.and here is what i did
`Point p1=new Point(66.9969,6.65428); //i took this coordinate from my gps device for demonstration
        Point p2=(Point) GeometryEngine
                .project(p1,
                        SpatialReference.create(4326),
                        mMapView.getSpatialReference());
        Graphic graphic = new Graphic(p2, new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.DIAMOND));
        mGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphic);//mGraphicsLayer is my graphic layer on my map view`
when i run my program the marker was not there on my mMapview.but when i changed the statment  `mMapView.getSpatialReference()` with `SpatialReference.create(32637)` the marker appeared in exactly the right possesion i wanted it to be,so my Question is why this is happening?I checked my mMapview spatial reference **id** and **latestid** and and it is **102100and** **3857** recpectively

Comment: Was the spatial reference of your map set? Data can only be projected on-the-fly if *both* are set (and compatible) You have set your point WGS84 (EPSG:4326) but I can't see here what the mMapView spatial reference is, you assert it to WGS84 UTM Zone 37 North (EPSG:32637) and it projects.. makes me think it wasn't set first. EPSG:102100 is Esri Web Mercator (on WGS84) which looks like 'default' to me.